# HTML CSS Nav Bar issue

Tags: html, css, flask

So, I'm currently making a website and for this website i'll obviously have a nav bar, I've been trying to fix this issue on mobile where the navbar slides under all of my display and I can't figure out how to fix it.. (Photo below)

[Nav Bar Under Displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZV7A.jpg)

But on browser It works perfectly :/ I cant figure it out

[I'm trying to get it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVsPc.png)

```
.nav-links, body {
    max-width: -100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: sticky;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.404);
    font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.logo{
    color: #ffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links a{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 19px;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code snippet, so that we can get to know what and how you are trying.

Comment: pls post your code so we know what you have tried

Comment: have you tried to add a high z-index on your navbar eg. `z-index: 99;` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried adding that nothing worked :/

Comment: I actually Can't figure out the issue, I don't know if it's todo with any other CSS or just the Nav, But The Nav Sits and slides under the Display and I can't seem to figure out how to fix it and make it sit above, This issue is only able to be recreated by being on a phone (IE, Safari, Google Chrome etc):